# Why should I be using interfaces (models) in Typescript / Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular6

The way I see it, defining objects with models seems to make them rigid and less change tolerant, making it easier to break an application in the future and adding lines of code for no gain. For instance I could have a get method that returns a video object from an API and program it as Any or as a defined model.

/model/video.ts

```
export interface Video {
// my code
 }
```

/pages/videos.ts

```
getAllVideos(): Promise<Video> {
// my code
}
```

vs.

/pages/videos.ts

```
getAllVideos(): Promise<Any> {
// my code
}
```

The way I see it. Less lines of code, less complexity, less files and less rigidity is a good thing. Why even have models defined?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ...making it easier to break an application in the future...

This is exactly the opposite of what happens when you introduce interfaces to JS with Typescript.

Let's say you have a function that accepts objects with a certain shape, like so

```
function giveMeStuff(obj) {
  return obj.foo.toLowerCase();
}
```

In this case, we have no way to make sure that when we call `giveMeStuff` we are actually passing an object which has `foo` property, which also needs to be a string.

If a new developer (or yourself, a few weeks later) comes along and calls `giveMeStuff(12)`, the code will break at runtime.

---

Instead, this is what happens when you have an interface.

```
function giveMeStuff(obj: IObjectWithFoo): string {
  return obj.foo.toLowerCase();
}

interface IObjectWithFoo {
  foo: string;
}
```

now, when you try to call `giveMeStuff(12)` the compiler will warn you that you can't do that, because the function is expecting a different kind of argument.

Comment: I see now. So we're moving error handling from runtime to the compiler and potentially getting better error messages as well.

Comment: The main advantage is the ability to catch preventable errors at compile time.

Comment: I do think it's a significant investment of labor (and app complexity) in exchange for moving the errors to compile time. However I also see how it would be very useful on large enterprise apps with lots of developers and complex deployments. Less so for small apps, it seems.

Comment: Well, note that the difference between an error at compile time and one at runtime is huge. In the first case, you won't be able to deploy your application with code that could potentially break (which is a very desirable condition), in the second one, you can do whatever you want, but the app will probably crash as soon as something unexpected happens.

Answer (score 3):

There are situations where is more important have a well defined interface. It depends on which requirements you are fulfilling, on the risk of the application and so on.

For example in a particular project it may be more importat to force to use that method with that object type, reducing errors probabilities.